# JQuery calculation plugin - remove value of 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the jQuery calculation (version 0.4.09) plugin to work out the total amount of two table cells. In the total price field the value is being set to 0 which I don't want. When looking into the jquery.field.js file at the parseNumber() method I can see that this is being set a 0 on line 137:

```
// if the value is null, use 0
if( v == null ){
v = 0; // update value
// if there's a error callback, execute it
if( jQuery.isFunction(options.onParseError) ) options.onParseError.apply($el,  [sMethod]);
$.data($el[0], "calcParseError", true);
```

I have tried removing this check, but then presented with 'NaN' message in the total price input field.

Is there a way around this? as i don't want the values to default to 0 when a user is filling out the form.

Many Thanks

Comment: You should find the line which is adding that value into the DOM. Verify there if is 0 and if it is, change it with empty string

Comment: numerous ways to use the plugin... create a demo in jsfiddle.net . Do you really need a plugin to calculate 2 cells?